# Can I use CSS selectors in Tritium for moving/copying elements?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I am trying to copy an element to a given CSS selector in Tritium.

The Tritum Spec lists the signature for copy_to as:

```
copy_to(Text %xpath)
```

http://tritium.io/simple-mobile/1.0.224#Node.copy_to(Text%20%25xpath)

I am trying to do:

```
copy_to(  CSS_SELECTOR )
```

For e.g:

```
copy_to("#header")
```

I cant seem to get this to work.

Here is the Tritium Tester URL: http://tester.tritium.io/4193cf46a239b4ff440cf1b4c36fb703cd22a5a4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that won't work because of the way CSS selectors work in Tritium.

According to the spec, CSS selectors are converted into XPath local searches, which means they are scoped.

```
html() {
  $("/html") {
    $$("#header > img") {
      add_class("logo")
    }
    $$("#content") {
      $("./div[@id='courses']"){
        $$("a") {
          attribute("href", "http://console.moovweb.com/learn/training/getting_started/generate")
        }
        copy_to(css('#header'), "before")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your example, your `copy_to` function is in the scope of `$("./div[@id='courses']")`, so it won't find the `div#header` in there.

You'll have to use an XPath selector like this: `copy_to("/html/body/div[@id='header']","before")`

See here: http://tester.tritium.io/5f0ae313a4f43038ee4adeb49b81236bfbc5f097